# how to deal with yokohama 215 45 r18 tier side wall damage

Tags: car, frontier

I think the damage is this part, should i replace it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If its a deep gash (looks like it is), just replace it.

Risking driving on a tire with a weak sidewall could cause a blow out when cornering, which is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: Agree here - there may be de-laminatibg occurring inside as well, so for your safety and others replace it. Sad about the cost....

Answer (score 0):

As long as the metal wireframe under the rubber is not exposed I don't see a reason to replace the tire.

You will want to monitor tire pressure over the coming days and weeks though.